# Can't combine two df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have two df,

dataset2:

```
    0   c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6  c7  c8  c9  ... c11 c12 c13 c14 c15 c16 c17 c18 c19 c20
0   s1  5   4   4   5   4   4   4   4   4   ... 4   4   3   3   4   3   4   4   3   3
1   s2  3   4   3   4   4   5   3   5   3   ... 5   3   3   2   3   3   3   5   5   1
2   s3  4   4   5   5   4   4   4   4   4   ... 5   4   4   1   3   2   3   3   4   3
3   s4  5   5   5   1   5   5   5   5   1   ... 4   5   5   1   5   4   5   4   5   5
4   s5  5   5   5   5   5   5   4   5   2   ... 4   4   5   1   2   2   5   5   5   3
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
74  s75 4   4   4   4   5   5   5   5   5   ... 5   5   4   2   5   4   4   5   5   4
75  s76 5   3   4   5   5   5   4   5   4   ... 5   4   4   4   4   3   3   4   5   4
76  s77 5   3   3   5   2   3   3   3   3   ... 3   3   5   5   3   3   5   3   5   3
77  s78 4   5   4   2   2   4   4   4   5   ... 5   5   3   3   4   2   4   5   5   2
78  s79 5   4   5   5   5   5   4   5   5   ... 5   5   4   2   5   3   4   5   5   4
```

df_combinec:

```
    0    c1 c2  c3  c4  c5  c6  c7  c8  c9  ... c11 c12 c13 c14 c15 c16 c17 c18 c19 c20
0   s80  5  5   5   6   4   3   4   3   2   ... 4   2   5   8   3   2   4   4   5   4
1   s81  5  4   4   5   3   4   5   4   3   ... 5   5   5   6   5   3   3   3   5   4
2   s82  4  4   4   6   5   4   4   5   6   ... 5   4   4   1   4   2   4   5   4   3
3   s83  5  4   4   5   5   5   2   4   4   ... 5   5   5   7   4   2   4   5   5   4
4   s84  3  2   5   4   5   5   4   5   5   ... 4   5   5   4   4   3   4   5   4   3
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
116 s196 4  4   4   5   5   4   5   5   4   ... 5   4   4   3   3   4   4   3   5   5
117 s197 5  5   4   5   5   5   4   5   4   ... 5   5   4   2   5   3   5   5   5   3
118 s198 5  5   4   6   4   4   5   4   2   ... 5   5   4   0   5   1   4   4   5   4
119 s199 5  3   3   4   4   5   5   5   5   ... 5   4   5   2   4   3   5   5   5   5
120 s200 5  4   4   4   3   5   2   5   3   ... 4   4   5   4   2   1   4   5   5   4
```

I try below code to combine these df, but it comes out many Nan.

```
dataset2.reset_index(drop=True)
df_combinec.reset_index(drop=True)
comb_data = pd.concat([dataset2,df_combinec], ignore_index=True)
```

df_combinec after reindex:

[image]

comb_data:
[image]

How to solve it?

Comment: can you check/print df_combinec after you reset index? somehow the column seems has comma in it

Comment: can i chk `dataset2.columns` and  `df_combinec.columns` ?

Comment: hmm... it should be fine, can you check whether the column name of both dataframe is the same? one way to make sure that they are same is add `df_combinec.columns=dataset2.columns` before combine

Comment: I use `df_combinec.columns=dataset2.columns` and slove! thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Leo Chen can you try mozway solution to be safe. it has better solution on this

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is likely caused by a single level MultiIndex in the second DataFrame.

Here is an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2]], columns=['A', 'B'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[3, 4]], columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['A', 'B']]))

pd.concat([df, df2])

#      A    B  (A,)  (B,)
# 0  1.0  2.0   NaN   NaN
# 0  NaN  NaN   3.0   4.0
```

You can solve the issue by flattening the MultiIndex to normal Index:

```
df2.columns = df2.columns.get_level_values(0)
pd.concat([df, df2])

#    A  B
# 0  1  2
# 0  3  4
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment, it seems your df_combinec dont have same columns as your dataset2

by putting `df_combinec.columns=dataset2.columns` before `concat` can solve the problem

but I think it is better to check your dataframe input too
if you read it from csv, better check them and make sure the first line always same, or maybe the encoding (I wonder about this)

Note: mozway's solution is better and safer if you have different order of columns on df_combinec

Comment: This is a dangerous solution, if for some reason the order of the columns is not exactly the same, this will silently swap column names

Comment: yes I agree with that, that is why I suggest to check more about the data itself, this can be temporary fix but not permanent

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, your column names are not matching. Review output of `dataset2.columns` and `df_combinec.columns`.

You can also try `numpy.concatenate()`; but make sure your column order is correct.

```py
comb_data = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate((dataset2.values, df_combinec.values), axis=0))
comb_data.columns = [ '0', 'c1', 'c2' ... 'c20' ]
```